# DATEPART in Sequelize ORM

Tags: sql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

Is there any option for T-SQL `DATEPART` equivalent in Sequelize ORM?

Sequelize's between operator has an option to place the table field on the left side, but I wanted to do something like below but with `DATEPART` option

```
const Schedules= await Schedules.findAll({
   where: {
    *DATEPART here*
    Date.now() : { 
     [Op.between]: [ startdate, enddate ]
    }
   }
```

I want to write a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM schedules
WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) BETWEEN DATEPART(HOUR, startdate) AND DATEPART(HOUR, enddate)
```

Here is my model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Schedules = sequelize.define(
        "Schedules",
        {
            title: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING(255),
                allowNull: false,
            },
            startdate: {
                type: Sequelize.DATE,
                allowNull: false,
            },
            enddate: {
                type: Sequelize.DATE,
                allowNull: false,
            },
        },
        {
            freezeTableName: true
        }
    );
    return Schedules;
};
```

Sequelize version: 6.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Sequelize.fn` and `Sequelize.where` to combine and compare SQL function result values:

```js
const Schedules= await Schedules.findAll({
   where: {
    [Op.and]: [
Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('DATE', Sequelize.literal('HOUR'), Sequelize.fn('getdate')), Op.gte, Sequelize.fn('DATE', Sequelize.literal('HOUR'), Sequelize.col('startdate'))),

Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('DATE', Sequelize.literal('HOUR'), Sequelize.fn('getdate')), Op.lte, Sequelize.fn('DATE', Sequelize.literal('HOUR'), Sequelize.col('enddate')))
]
}
```